# Android: align two images

Tags: android, imageview, alignment

I'm trying to put 2 `Imageview` in `LinearLayout`, but I don't align well with it. I want them to appear:

|<----SPACE---->**IMAGE 1**<----SPACE---->**IMAGE 2**<----SPACE---->|

But the 2 images on the left without margin. This is my code:

**JAVA**

```
    int tercioPantalla = Modulo.anchoPantalla(this) / 3;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(tercioPantalla, tercioPantalla / 2);
    layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    ruta1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(tercioPantalla, tercioPantalla / 2);
    layoutParams3.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    ruta2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
```

**Modulo.anchoPantalla**

```
public static int anchoPantalla(Context context) {

    int ancho = 0;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    ancho = (int) (metrics.widthPixels);

    return ancho;
}
```

**XML**

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bus_ruta1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ruta1_selector" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bus_ruta2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ruta2_selector" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ruta1_selector" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bus_ruta2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ruta2_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_icon = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

ruta1.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);
ruta2.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);
```

Comment: +1, I was writing the very same thing... In addition, he doesn't need to set the gravity in code, since it's done in the layout.

Comment: This was my old code. But I want width and height programatically with width screen

Comment: @Hariharan: You're welcome. I would have given the same layout, so I think it's really the correct answer. You only forgot to add some margin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just seen yours `LinearLayout` , in my opinion you can use `android:layout_weight` and give equal weight to each `ImageView` as   `android:layout_weight="1"` for both, Hope will solve the issue.

Comment: This was my old code. But I want width and height programatically with width screen

Answer (score 0):

Just use weight, martin parameters to customize your layout:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/status_left_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/status_arrow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/status_center_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/status_arrow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/status_right_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/status_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This was my old code. But I want width and height programatically with width screen

Comment: There is no weight parameters in your code, just try it, your elements  will be replaсed in correct proportion of your screen, and you don't need to use any code